# Python- Parts of my code aren't working and I can't figure out why

Tags: python, function, functional-programming, program-entry-point

This is for an into to python class. I have to at least use a main function and 2 other functions. When I run the run, it just prints "Have you booked your trip already? Please enter yes or no" over and over again. Instead, I'm trying to get it to first ask the person if they have booked their trip or not. If yes, it continues to ask their gender. And then the season of their destination. The program then generates a packing list accordingly.

```
# Welcome the user
def main():
   print('Welcome the Personalized Packing List Generator. '
         'In order to generate your list, you will have to provide some information about yourself and your trip.')


# function that checks whether the users' trip has been booked or not.
def tripBooked():
   booked = input("Have you booked your trip already? Please enter yes or no.")
   if booked == 'no' or booked == 'No':
       print('Please return once your trip has been confirmed')
   else:
       print('Lets get to know you a bit better')


# Lists 1-4 are for everyone
list1 = ("Documents: Tickets, passport, itinerary.")
list2 = ("Clothing: Tops, pants, shoes, socks, undergarments.")
list3 = ("Electronics: Chargers, headphones.")
list4 = ('Hygiene: Toothbrush, toothpaste, floss, deodorant, hairbrush.')
# List 5 is for women
list5 = ("Makeup and cosmetics, jewelry, handbag, hair ties, straightener or curling rod.")
# List 6 is for men
list6 = ("Ties, cufflinks, razor, shaving gel, after shave.")
# List 7 for winter
list7 = ("Coat, hat, scarf, boots, warm socks, thermals.")
# List 8 is for fall/spring
list8 = ("Outerwear: Light jacket, cardigan, raincoat.")
# List 9 for summer
list9 = ('Flip flops, sunscreen, hat, bathing suit, sunglasses.')

finalList = list1 + list2 + list3 + list4


# List generator function
def genderListGenerator():
   gender = input('What is your identified gender? Please enter male or female.')

print('Here is what we recommend as basic things to take with you:', finalList)


if "male" == genderListGenerator() or genderListGenerator() == 'Male':
   print('finalList += list6')
elif genderListGenerator() == 'female' or genderListGenerator() == 'Female':
   print('finalList += list5')


def seasonListGenerator():
   season = input('What season is it where you are going? Please enter winter, fall, spring,  or summer.')


if seasonListGenerator == "winter" or seasonListGenerator == 'Winter':
   print('finalList += list7')
if "fall" or seasonListGenerator == 'Fall' or "spring" == seasonListGenerator or seasonListGenerator == 'Spring':
   print('finalList += list8')
if seasonListGenerator == "summer" or seasonListGenerator == 'Summer':
   print('finalList += list9')
```

Comment: Are you familiar with debug tools ? Using step by step executing would greatly improve your ability to spot the execution flow issue by yourself. Most of the time, it saves lots of stackoverflow question from existing in the first place.

Comment: The `genderListGenerator()` function does not return a value (and therefore it returns `None` by default.)  So when you do a comparison like `if "male" == genderListGenerator()`, that comparison will never be true.

Comment: This prooves the whole point of : 1- using a debugger, 2- Thinking of the program flow, variables, exchanges before coding anything, 3- reading documentation about functions calls and return values

Comment: LoneWanderer- Unfortunately, we weren't taught debugging in my class and I don't have enough time to teach myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be a good idea to use your main function to control the flow of your program. Also, make your functions return values and store them to variables in your main program, this way those functions only get called once and the user's input is saved for further use. 
I took the liberty of rewriting your code, it should work better now:

```
# Lists 1-4 are for everyone
list1 = ("Documents: Tickets, passport, itinerary.")
list2 = ("Clothing: Tops, pants, shoes, socks, undergarments.")
list3 = ("Electronics: Chargers, headphones.")
list4 = ('Hygiene: Toothbrush, toothpaste, floss, deodorant, hairbrush.')

# List 5 is for women
list5 = ("Makeup and cosmetics, jewelry, handbag, hair ties, straightener or curling rod.")
# List 6 is for men
list6 = ("Ties, cufflinks, razor, shaving gel, after shave.")

# List 7 for winter
list7 = ("Coat, hat, scarf, boots, warm socks, thermals.")
# List 8 is for fall/spring
list8 = ("Outerwear: Light jacket, cardigan, raincoat.")
# List 9 for summer
list9 = ('Flip flops, sunscreen, hat, bathing suit, sunglasses.')

# function that checks whether the users' trip has been booked or not.
def tripBooked():
    booked = input("Have you booked your trip already? Please enter yes or no. ")
    if booked == 'no' or booked == 'No':
        print('Please return once your trip has been confirmed')
        return False
    else:
        print('Lets get to know you a bit better')
        return True


# List generator function
def genderListGenerator():
    gender = input('What is your identified gender? Please enter male or female. ')

    return gender


def seasonListGenerator():
    season = input('What season is it where you are going? Please enter winter, fall, spring,  or summer. ')

    return season


# Welcome the user
def main():
    print('Welcome the Personalized Packing List Generator. '
        'In order to generate your list, you will have to provide some information about yourself and your trip. ')

    if tripBooked():

        finalList = [list1, list2, list3, list4]

        gender = genderListGenerator()

        if gender in ['male', 'Male']:
            finalList.append(list6)
        elif gender in ['female', 'Female']:
            finalList.append(list5)


        season = seasonListGenerator()

        if season in ["winter", 'Winter']:
            finalList.append(list7)
        if season in ["fall", 'Fall', "spring", 'Spring']:
            finalList.append(list8)
        if season in ["summer", 'Summer']:
            finalList.append(list9)

        print('Here is what we recommend as basic things to take with you:',)
        for l in finalList:
            print(l)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Thank you! This works much better. If I want to add in something like 'Thank you for using this service" would that go in at the bottom, before the "if __name__ == "__main__":" part?

Comment: @TanishSingh You can add it to the end of the main() function. Adding it to the bottom of the code would also work, but think of the main() function as a form of flow control for your code.

Answer (score 0):

def seasonListGenerator():
    season = input('What season is it where you are going? Please enter winter, fall, 
    spring,  or summer.')
    if season == "winter":
        print('finalList += list7')
    elif (season == "fall" or season == 'Fall' or season == "spring" ):
        print('finalList += list8')
    else:
        print('finalList += list9')
    genderListGenerator()
    seasonListGenerator()

Comment: I changed the last part of you code and it works perfect!!

Comment: Can you fix the code block formatting so it appears as code? I tried doing that for you but I was uncertain how your indentation was supposed to appear. The first way I tried it made this function recursive, which I'm assuming was not the intention. Please also include some explanation for the solution in the answer. Click here to -> [edit]